# How to measure magnitude of chaotic behavior?

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Not necessarily Lyapunov time. In a higher dimensional model, suppose you have many rooms in a house with various heating sources. This is then modeled by a large matrix of coefficients of heat transfer equations, but such a large system of nonlinear equations is prone to chaotic behavior. Realistically though, the temperatures of many rooms don't fluctuate too rapidly after the house attains some kind of equilibrium but retains some due some from the culmination of many turbulent flows.

How do you quantify this notion of "not too chaotic"? Because the manifolds in the solution space could be very turbulent, but their overall magnitude in proportion to the equilibrium temperature may not be that great.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you should just go for the amplitude. You do not seem to actually care about chaoticity (whatever that may be). It doesn’t matter for your application whether the oscillation is periodic, quasiperiodic or chaotic.

Comment: But how do I "know" that I don't need to care the oscillation form? Without some way of quantifying how much the temperature fluctuates through chaotic motion, I won't know.

Comment: I am not exactly sure that I understand your problem. If you have an sufficiently long simulation of your system, you just take the amplitude of the oscillations in that simulation (i.e., the difference between the maximum and minimum value) after initial equilibration. Most chaotic oscillations will not relevantly exceed this, i.e., they do not suddenly exhibit excessive amplitudes a.k.a. extreme events. Now, if you want to ensure the absence of extreme events, things get complicated, but that’s a far deeper question, depends on what you can do, and still is not about quantifying chaoticity.

Comment: Perhaps what is missing then are bounds. Is it possible to state temperature in a house will never exceed or be lower than a certain range?

Comment: @PhiEarl: Yes. But how to do this depends on details such as your model, what simulations you are willing to run and what certainty you need. I would expect that for most applications something like “we simulated the system for hundred years and all temperatures were within this interval” suffices and is the easiest way.

Comment: But that is empirical, not theoretical. How would it be predicted in advance to establish theoretical bounds in a differential model?

Comment: @PhiEarl: Many quantifiers of Chaos and similar can often only be determined empirically, e.g., Lyapunov exponents/time. Depending on your model, obtaining any useful analytical bounds can be insanely hard, if not impossible.

Comment: But isn't boundedness an intrinsic property of chaotic behavior? Why hasn't there been any development in determining those bounds?

Comment: It’s not that there is nothing, but it depends on your system. Without specifics, I cannot say much. I can build systems that seem to exhibit a consistent chaotic oscillation for a very long simulation time and then suddenly change their behaviour to a higher amplitude, non-chaotic behaviour, or even unbounded behaviour. It’s admittedly very unlikely that a model of temperature in a house exhibits such a behaviour, but without further data, it’s hard to say more.